# left side menu in magento modern theme

Tags: magento

First of all many many thanks

I want to create a magento web site with left side menu(all categories added from admin side) in modern theme. But i don't know any idea. Please give me a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Magento? A left category list was added in version 1.4 but only shows for non-anchor categories with sub-categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to implement mine...

http://dx3webs.com/front/2010/01/create-a-left-hand-navigation-verticle-category-in-magento/

It works great as long as you follow the directions